# Escaping single quotes in stringified JSON thats passed as EJS template to view

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, ejs

I have a NodeJS app that uses EJS templating for injecting variables from the server into the view. I'm having trouble with a particular value, which is an array containing objects whose values may contain an apostrophe. I have to wrap the EJS template string in a single quote when passing to JSON.parse, and as a result the apostrophe gets confused as the end of the string being passed to JSON.parse. I've tried escaping the apostrophe with no luck.

```
<script>
  window.foo = JSON.parse('<%- JSON.stringify([{"bar": "baz's lorem ipsum"}]) %>');
</script>
```

**Interprets to:**

```
<script>
  // the string is cut off between the first quote & baz's apostrophe
  window.foo = JSON.parse('[{"bar": "baz's lorem ipsum"}]');
</script>
```

Comment: Are we talking about server code or client code? It's unclear what you are trying to achieve. Btw the single quote should be escaped anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`JSON.stringify` return a valid JSON text representation of object. You do not need to parse it back:

```
<script>
  window.foo = <%- JSON.stringify([{"bar": "baz's lorem ipsum"}]) %>;
</script>
```